# How to add multiple radio buttons in single cell in Datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, radio-button

I need to add three radio buttons in single cell in data grid view in c# windows forms.

[image]

I need like this "3 radio buttons in single cell". I am using datagridview in windows form.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: Out of the box you could use a combo instead; the user can quickly select an item by pressing B, V or O?

Comment: For my case, I need to use radio button.

Comment: You can replace the Cell's EditControl with any other existing Control or custom object. You may want a UserControl here. See: [Customizing the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/customizing-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control) -> [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a column for each choice as shown below. The last three columns are images. Since the code to implement is more than what seems prudent to post here check out the source in the following [GitHub repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/DataGridViewWithRadioButtons/tree/master/DataGridViewFalseRadioButton).

The [code](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/DataGridViewWithRadioButtons/blob/master/DataGridViewFalseRadioButton/Form1.cs#L25:L57) to handle selection changes for last three columns

**Edit** Download the image, give it an extension of .zip, open and you will have all the source code. See [instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/119365/how-to-hide-zip-files-inside-a-picture-without-any-extra-software/).

[image]

Comment: *Since the code to implement is more than what seems prudent to post here* - it should still be replicated here in case the linked page changes or dies. A trick you can consider is to [embed a zip of the source code into a GIF](https://www.howtogeek.com/119365/how-to-hide-zip-files-inside-a-picture-without-any-extra-software/) and host the GIF on the SO imgur like any other picture; users can download the pic, rename to .zip and open with a capable archiver such as WinRAR to retrieve the packed files

Comment: @CaiusJard, sounds good but not sure about time to do the "trick" and if not will look at slimming down the code and post here later today. Thanks.

Comment: Here's an app that implements the trick: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMpkt.gif - d/l, rename to zip, open with winrar, extract SoZip sln and open in VS - it's only about 5 lines of code (shows openfiledialog, read all bytes of zip, read all bytes of file, write concatenation of gifbytes + zipbytes)

Comment: Just changed the image to include a zip in the image for the project source code.